# Retrieving audio from Web SQL Database and playing with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, arraybuffer

I have the code saving an `ArrayBuffer` (from an `XMLHttpRequest` call to get an mp3 as an arraybuffer) to a web SQL database, retrieving it from a SQL query which returns an object `ArrayBuffer`. However, when I try to `decodeAudioData` or `createBuffer` I get a type error.

```
var buffer = audioContext.createBuffer(result.xtalk,false);
```

gives an:

> Uncaught TypeError: Type error

if I put an alert in result.xtalk is object `ArrayBuffer`.

This is in Chrome 21.0.1180.75 on a Mac.

I tried creating an `ArrayBuffer` and filling it byte by byte then passing that - but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial.May this would help

```
var dogBarkingBuffer = null;
var context = new webkitAudioContext();

function loadDogSound(url) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

   // Decode asynchronously
  request.onload = function() {
  context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
    dogBarkingBuffer = buffer;
  }, onError);
}
request.send();
```

}

Refer the following link:-
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Also do "typeof" on the arraybuffer object you  are receiving.Arraybuffer have a properties called byteLength.

If its undefined that means the object you received from the sql database is not arraybuffer object

Reference:-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer

Comment: Thast is what I am doing, except saving ArrayBuffer object in onload and retrieving it back to play. I also saved it as a Blob and tried to retrieve and convert it to ArrayBuffer. It seems be just saving the text [object Blob] or [object ArrayBuffer] if I debug the web sql database which may well be the issue. Or the debugger is not telling the correct value. typeof coming back from web sql database is string so looks like the web sql in chrome and safari is not storing the blob

Answer (score 0):

Pulse allows reading SQL query results to text or playing mp3 files based on queries:
https://www.timestored.com/pulse/help/faq/audio-alerts